# Build task for AspectJ fails due to undefined name

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

I'm having issues with creating an ant task to compile for AspectJ. It seems to be a namespace issue, with ant not recognizing the task name "aspectj:iajc." Any idea why this might be?

Error message:

```
build.xml:122: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.aspectj:iajc 
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

Added jars to WEB-INF/lib directory:

- aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar
- aspectjtools-1.6.2.jar
- aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

Added namespace to project element:

```
<project xmlns:aspectj="antlib:org.aspectj">
```

Added iajc task to compile target:

```
<target name="compile">
...
    <aspectj:iajc source="1.6" sourceroots="../src" destDir="./${final.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="./lib/"> 
                <include name="**/*.jar" /> 
            </fileset>      
        </classpath>
    </aspectj:iajc>
...
</target>
```

I tried changing the source parameter in the iajc task to "1.8" to match the jrt package, but got the same error message.

Reference:

- http://java.dzone.com/news/aspectj-and-ant

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but here is an offer: If switching to Maven is an option for you, I can help you. I use AspectJ with Maven a lot, but have never used Ant because I do not like scripted builds.

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to get it working with Ivy.

Comment: Then please do not leave the question open and unanswered but either answer it by yourself and accept your own answer in order to close the question and help others in the same situation or delete the question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what was wrong with my previous approach, but I was able to make it work using a taskdef, which allows you to specific the path to the aspectj jar file.

```
<taskdef resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="./lib/aspectjtools-1.8.5.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```